# open specific view controller when I click on local notification presented in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotifications

I want, when I click on the local notification which is presented to me, the specific view controller that is `DummyControler` should be presented.

I have done in this way but when I run my app it fails.

Help me to go on the specific view controller when I click on the notification

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

if (launchOptions != nil) {
    // Launched from local notification
    NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];


    UINavigationController * nav = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    //NotificationPreviewViewConroller
    UIViewController *vc=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DummyViewController"];
    [nav pushViewController:vc animated: false];

 }

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];    
 return YES;
}
```

Comment: local notification which is when presennted

Comment: what error or problem your facing?

Comment: @dreamBegin I am trying to got to the specific VIewcontroller when I click on the notification but I am unable to handle this

Comment: does it enter the if block?
Have you tried putting a break point?

Comment: where should I put the break point??

Comment: inside the if condition, also, what's the value of `nav` when the code is executed?

Comment: @AatishMolasi nothing happen

Comment: so it's not entering the if condition, yes?

Comment: @AatishMolasi yes right bro

Comment: is `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ` being called?

Answer (score 0):

Your rootcontroller is type of `UIViewController` not `UINavigationController`

Please replace

```
UINavigationController * nav = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    //NotificationPreviewViewConroller
    UIViewController *vc=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DummyViewController"];
    [nav pushViewController:vc animated: false];
```

To

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    //NotificationPreviewViewConroller
    UIViewController *vc=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DummyViewController"];
    [self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:vc animated: false];
```

This will work.

Please repalce above code by following updated.

**Update:-**

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    //NotificationPreviewViewConroller
    UIViewController *vc=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DummyViewController"];
    [self.window.rootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated: false];
```

Comment: error: No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'pushViewController:animated:'

Comment: after update its still showing initial controller not the what we want `DummyViewController` :)

Comment: if-condition does not run

Answer (score 0):

As you said "I want, when I click on the local notification which is presented to me, the specific view controller that is DummyControler should be presented."

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
DummyControler *vc=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DummyViewController"];
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:true completion:^{
   //Completion code 
}];
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170420/discussion-between-dreambegin-and-ios-developer).